# Openerp using subreport by Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, odoo

I want to create a sale order report with Jasper Report. So, I took xml of sale_order object by Jasper's data template of openerp and I set depth 3 in that xml file. And then, I created report by using Jasper Report. After that, I added this report by using new Jasper Report of openerp. My report has a dataset in the main report for sale_order_lines. So that, I have an error below:

**openerp.netsvc: Report Error Failed to invoke method execute in class com.nantic.jasperreports.JasperServer: Error evaluating expression : Source text : $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("//sub_report")**

How to fix this error? If you don't mind, please explain me step by step.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error evaluating expression in Openerp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674952/error-evaluating-expression-in-openerp)

Comment: It is a bad practice to repost the question

Comment: yes, it's the same question of Error evaluating expression in Openerp. But anybody didn't answer and this question was closed. I really really want to know this answer so I asked again. What should I do? Please answer me.

Comment: @shariphwar Basically when a question on StackOverflow is closed it means the question is not up to standards. In your case, the previous question (and this copy paste) did not really provide enough detail to be answered. When your question is closed it does not necessarily mean forever. You can edit the question, providing more detail, like source code and/or short complete example to produce the problem. See [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more ideas.